# How can I run a script after importing it?

Tags: python, module, python-import

**Problem**

I would like to import a script containing many functions and then run them, so that I can use the function. I may have misunderstood the purpose of import. I am working in Jupyter.

**Reprex**

```
#Create the script in a local folder

%%writefile test.py
c = 500

def addup(a,b,c):
    return a*b + (c)
```

```
#import the file and use it

import test
addup(1,5,c)


#Error message

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-1-71cb0c70c39d> in <module>
#       1 import test
# ----> 2 addup(1,5,c)

# NameError: name 'addup' is not defined
```

**Any help appreciated.**

Comment: Modules (`.py` files) have their own variable namespace. And usually you import a function and not the call of a function.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to imitate what happens in R where you break up a long script into separate files and then load in the separate files (with their functions, variables etc) via "source('separate file.r')". It avoids having really long scripts. Is that something I can do in Python?

Comment: test is the name of a  python package, so when you import test you are importing the module and not the file, change the name of file from test.py to something else

Comment: Sourcing a file in R and importing a module in Python are fundamentally different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not called the function! You need a dot `.` to call a function from a module.

This is the correct syntax:

```py
import test
result = test.addup(1,5,c)
```

Import a specific function:

```py
from test import addup
addup(1,5,c)
```

Importing all of the module's functions:

```py
from test import *
addup(1,5,c) # this way you can use any function from test.py without the need to put a dot
```